# How to format float to 6 decimal places

Tags: c#, formatting, numbers

I use following method to for conversion:

```
f.ToString("### ### ##0.### ###", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It seems to work fine for all values, except when have many decimal digits (more then 4).
If I type `123.456789` the float takes value of `123.456787` (displayed by debugger). But when I use above method it outputs `123.456 8` string.

I was expecting to get `123.456 787`

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=net-5.0) "By default, the return value only contains 7 digits of precision although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally." This is for `float` not `double` obviously

Comment: @Charlieface Hym, casting to `double` seem to do the tick but somehow the float's method has no problem with displaying "100 000 000" which I believe has more then 7 digits... I dived into "For more information about numeric format specifiers, see Standard Numeric Format Strings and Custom Numeric Format" and didn't see that last paragraph...